# auto.arima throws error wrong length for 'fixed'

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, error-message

I am using auto.arima from the R forecast package.
When using this function with lambda parameter, it is throwing error

```
wrong length for 'fixed'
```

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
library(forecast)

t <- c(5354969,5714384,6993786,8134965,7291882,7855863,8260187,10187979,8472624,9317541,8667358,10245900,8140618,7501393,7592070,9683767,8327092,9042875,9835730,10828364,8200433,8516591,8290409,8406130,6587574,8174418)
myts <- ts(t, frequency = 4)

f <- forecast(auto.arima(myts, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, lambda = "auto"), h = 2)

# Alternative

lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(myts)
f <- forecast(auto.arima(myts, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, lambda = lambda), h = 2)
```

Comment: My R version is 3.52 and forecast package is version 8.6

Answer (score -1):

I don't use or recommend auto.arima if anomalies (pulses) or level shifts or local time trends or seasonal pulses are in the data BUT I do know some things about the Box-Cox lambda optimization process . Some formulations use the geometric mean ...the nth root of the product of all n values . You might code your data say by dividing by 100000. to see if that "cures" the problem. Just my guess !

Note your 26 quarterly values appear to have some evidence of deterministic structure thus you may not be good to go with auto.arima as it uses (in this case ) a tarnished correlogram.

Following @Adam0 ..."The correlogram should be calculated from residuals using a model that controls for intervention administration, otherwise the intervention effects are taken to be Gaussian noise, underestimating the actual autoregressive effect."

[image]

[image]